npx resolving incorrect path to react native cli
I am trying to run react native run-android command, however it appears that my npx does not resolve packages in correct places:
Error: Cannot find module 'F:\Work\project\node_modules\node_modules\react-native\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

is there a way to manually tell npx where to find the package?
I have tried using full path to react-native/cli.js file, however that seems to not then see the arguments that are passed after it. Also tried specifying package location with -p, however then it prompts me to install the package each time even though it's already there
